# Weird margin alterations in IE8 Compatibility mode (IE7)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, margin

i'm suffering some odd changes in margin when viewing my page in IE8 compatibility mode (ie7). Specifically in 2 areas. The Primary navigation and the footer.

As you can see the navigation is experiencing a much larger margin from the left then what is seen in IE8/FF/Chrome/Safari

http://demo.carbonium.no/iebug1.png

Below the advertising there is supposed to be space. This problem persists in all IE browsers but not in FF/Chrome/Safari

[Here is a link to the actual site](http://havorn-fotball.carbonium.no/)

Comment: You've never had a helpful previous answer?

Comment: I did check out some of them in hopes of finding and answer but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i found a work around to the problem i was having with the navigation. Using absolute positioning and Z-index:1; to take the element out of the natural document flow solved the problem. Also it would seam that replacing margins with padding can to some degree give you the same result. Either way i am still confused as to why IE7 causes this particular issue.